# Slack ではメールアドレスを非表示に出来ないのでしょうか？

Tags: slack

プログラム勉強会のSlackに参加したのですが、驚いたのは「メールアドレスが公開されている」ことでした。
調べてみると、チャンネルの管理者の設定で「非表示」にできるようです。

https://slack.com/intl/ja-jp/help/articles/228020667
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

個人で非表示にする方法はありますか？

Comment: [製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)を見ると、スタックオーバフローでは扱えない「何故○○なのですか？」に当たってしまう印象です。